# Bounty pot for completely lost bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Per [the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

> If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on **the bounty will be lost forever**.

This sum shouldn't disappear, in my opinion; too many people lack the experience to correctly evaluate the amount that they should pick, especially for *complicated* questions.

**The solution is simple: keep that amount for future bounties on the same question**, which means that the next bounty will be combined with the current pot amount. The maximum pot amount would be 450 because over that threshold you wouldn't be able to start a new bounty on the question (since the minimum is 50).

Comment: As you can easily guess, this arose from the fact that I didn't put a bounty high enough on a question and the resulting regrets.

Comment: The standard answer to every question concerning "lost" bounties is: ***The bounty doesn't pay for answers, it pays for advertisement***.  You  should try to address that.  Also how would you address the pot and multiple user bounties.  If you place a bounty and it gets "lost", and I start a new bounty on that question.  Would my bounty include your pot?  If so, would I be responsible for awarding the rep from your lost bounty?

Comment: It's been [proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243042/invest-unused-rep-from-previous-unawarded-bounty-into-a-subsequent-bounty) on the global Meta.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Would my bounty include your pot?" of course it would! That's the beauty of it. The next bounty would always be bigger hence the exposure increases. I don't understand the downvotes really, it's a great solution to a hard problem: most ppl don't have that much reputation (to start two consecutive big bounties).

Comment: @Louis this is not exactly the same. In my proposal the bounty period is over; in his it's during a "grace period". So the pot is not shared in his proposal: the benefactor remains the same.

Comment: @Knu so, to continue my example, your "failed" bounty would go to help enhance my bounty, even if our goals were completely different, and our definition of a correct answer were different?

Comment: I like it, it's an original and interesting idea. It would probably see too many cases with an undesirable outcome though: users winning half of a giant bounty by default, because their answer happened to gain 2 upvotes during the bounty period.

Comment: Is this pot per-question, per-user, per-question-per-user, or global?

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's per question. Any new bounty will profit from it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 good point I didn't elaborate on the edge cases to simplify the matter. Of course the answers on the previous bounty would need at least 2 *new* upvotes as if they were starting anew (half win case).

Answer (score 3):

I don't dislike it. It's original and interesting. The basic thinking behind it is sound: if a bounty question doesn't get a useful answer, it is presumably a hard question, so having a bounty pot that grows (like in a lottery when no one wins the jackpot) and increases people's motivation to answer it makes sense.

Some potential problems could be solved through additional safeguards:

- to prevent people from using the system to post work assignments (any more than they already do), this would have to be limited to one bounty per question per user
- the auto-award feature would have to be turned off in these cases to prevent frivolous answers accidentally winning a huge pot of rep (or rather, half of it)

One big unsolved problem remains, though. *Who gets to award the jackpot?*

One could start a bounty on a question that already has a number piled up, and then award the entire sum to an undeserving answer - either as a fraud, or because they simply don't know better. Neither of the previous bounty starters can influence which answer their points go to. That's hardly acceptable.

The only alternative I can think of - put the awarding in the hands of the community and give the jackpot to the first new answer that gains a massive number of upvotes, say 10 or 15 - isn't really good, either: in low-volume tags the answer may never reach the requisite number of upvotes, plus a requirement like this would be a huge motivation to create sock puppet accounts to do the voting.

So - nice idea, but has too big implementation problems, IMO.